# How to checkout a remote branch and work on it in collaboration with other team members?

Tags: git, gitlab

This is all I want to do:

1. Clone the origin/master (i.e I'm on a fresh machine with no source code).
2. Switch to a different remote branch (i.e. it's not a local branch!!! It's something like origin/collaboration_branch).
3. Get all the current changes in the collaboration_branch (that are not necessarily merged into master yet).
4. Make changes in collaboration_branch.
5. Add changes to local staging, commit to local branch, push to remote origin/collaboration_branch.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout origin/collaboration_branch
# work on it... commit many revision
# then is when you will start hitting problems
git push origin HEAD:collaboration_branch
# if you were able to commit there, then your changes are into the branch, nothing else to do
```

**BUT** if anybody committed anything before you, you will start to have headaches because you are *not* working with a local branch. The easy way to move forward if that is the case is to rebase, so you don't start adding up merges:

```
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/collaboration_branch
```

Then you can try to push again.... but you are making your life more difficult than it should by skipping to use a local branch.

Comment: I never said that I want to "skip" using a local branch. All I want to do is contribute to origin/collaboration_branch without too many headaches.

Comment: When I clone the project, I'm in origin/master by default. When I try to switch to the other branch, I get this long convoluted git message that says I can experiment, etc, so it makes it sound like I'm not doing something right. I don't want to experiment with anything. I want to make changes and push to the remote branch.

Comment: Sure... you are in _detached HEAD state_....  because you ask to checkout a remote branch by specifying origin in the name of the branch. Try without prepending origin/ to the name of the branch and then git will create a local branch from the remote one.... and in step 2 you specify you want to work on a remote branch.